# What's the unit for radius in GeoFire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm creating a `query` using [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/), which accepts two parameters; `center` (a 1D array containing the values of `latitude` and `longitude` for the centre of the geospatial query), and `radius`, which in their [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoquery) is expected to be set as a scalar double value i.e. `10.5`.

What is the unit of the `radius`? I imagine it is likely `km`, but I haven't found any documentation to support this.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/v4.1.2/src/geoQuery.js#L411-L414

Comment: @cartant Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cartant: sounds like an answer ;-)

Comment: Actually, the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geofirequeryquerycriteria) does state that the radius is in kilometres.

Answer (score 3):

The unit for radius in a GeoFire query is Kilometers

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geofirequeryquerycriteria